# Webpack can't resolve MUI component unless '/index.js' is added to the import statement

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babeljs

I'm using React 18, Webpack 5, and Material UI 5. I've only previously used older versions of all of these, and the configurations were mostly handled by a colleague, so I have the sense I'm making some silly error.

I've installed MUI with `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` as stated in their docs. When I try to import, e.g., the `Box` component, I do it with `import Box from '@mui/material/Box'`; the module path has changed from what I'm familiar with, but this is more or less how I always imported their components. However, this throws a `Can't resolve '@mui/material/Box'` error in the Webpack compiler.

If I add `/index.js` to the end of the import statement, it works. Why do I have to add the `index.js`? Is it a configuration issue? How do I get it to find it on its own?

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server .",
    "build": "webpack ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^51.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "/dist"
    ],
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es2024": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": "latest",
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      "unicorn"
    ],
    "extends": "plugin:unicorn/recommended",
    "rules": {
      "unicorn/better-regex": "warn",
      "unicorn/filename-case": [
        "error",
        {
          "cases": {
            "kebabCase": true,
            "pascalCase": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import path from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default {
  entry: 'index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',
  },
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    port: '5000',
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that newer version of Webpack requires you to specify full module path by default. You can disable this behavior by setting `fullySpecified` field as `false` for specific module rule. Here is a [link to documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#resolvefullyspecified) with an example on how to do it:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false, // disable the behaviour
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Bogdan! This also solved the issue of having to specify the file extensions when importing my own components. I thought I had tried this option already, but maybe I put it in the wrong place before.